# Extract the last n results from a Paged Search

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am attempting to get the last 200 results from a paged search in SuiteScript 2.0. When I run the simple code I get the error

> "name":"INVALID_PAGE_RANGE","message":"Invalid page range: fetch."

What exactly am I doing wrong?

The below code was run in the NS debugger (I have removed some code for brevity):

```
function(ui, email, runtime, search, file, config, format, record, log) {

    var mySearch = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch_mht_lrf_export_to_lab'
        });

    // 200 results per page (am I correct here?)
    var results = mySearch.runPaged({pageSize:200});

    var count = results.count; // = 264

    // Obtain the last 200 results. From the documentation; 
    // index is 'The index of the page range that bounds the desired data.'
    // Error occurs on the next line
    var data = results.fetch({index: results.count});

    var x = 0;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've already answered this on the Slack group, but I'll copy my answer here in case someone one day has this question and comes across the post).

The `index` parameter that you pass to `results.fetch` is the index of the "page" of data that you want. In your example above, where you have 264 results and your page size is 200, there would be 2 pages of results. Results 1 - 199 would be on the first page (index = 0), and 200 - 264 on the second page.

In order to get the last 200 results, you will always need to retrieve the last 2 pages (unless the result count is an exact multiple of 200), and then just look at the final 200 of those results.